# Updating multiple mongoDB collections from node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update two seperate collections in a mongoDB database using mongoose and node.js. But I am getting an error for setting headers after they are sent.
[image: This is the error]

The code that is being used to set this up is : 
[image: Code]

Line 170 is the line where customer.update is written

Answer (score 3):

You trying to send response two times after customer and admin collection update. That's why you got this error.

To solve this. Use async library http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel

Or custom functions with callbacks and only send headers when all collections got updated.

here is example

```
async.parallel([
   adminName: function(callback) {
      admin.update({yourUpdateCode}, function(err, AdminDoc){
         //you may want to add error handling here
         callback(null, AdminDoc);
      });
   },
   customerName: function(callback) {
      customer.update({yourUpdateCode}, function(err,doc){
       //you may want to add error handling here
        callback(null, CustDoc);
      });
   }],
function(err, results) {
   // results is now equals to: {adminName: AdminDoc, customerName: CustDoc}
   //your final callback here.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do we need to install some specific npm package for this?

Comment: Well..You can use async lib as give you reference to DOCS. You can use promises if you want. You also can create methods that will update each collection and return final result to main function. About ASYNC. Yes you need to install it using npm.

Comment: ok. What is the collName referring to in your inital snippet?

Comment: Async each iterates over array of values and pass each value to callback function..Let me change example. So you understand better

Comment: Ya that will be great

Comment: what would be the final res.json type statement for it?

Comment: what would be the final res.json type statement for it?
res.json(adminName);
res.json(custName);
like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124714/discussion-between-nimit-bedi-and-mykola-borysyuk).

Comment: Hey..I tried this method..both the collections are getting updated, but the issue is that the command once sent, doesnt stop, it keeps running and has to to Aborted.
Following is the code that i wrote :

Comment: async.parallel([
    function(callback){
     admin.update({"username":donor},{$inc:{"amount":-amount}},function(err){
      if (err){
       callback(err);
       return 
      }
      callback();
     });
    },
    function(callback){
     customer.update({"username":recepient},{$inc:{"amount":amount}},callback);
    }],function(err){
     if (err) {throw err;}
     console.log('both are saved now');
    });